# Draw over 100 small images on Android Canvas each frame

Tags: android, canvas, unity-game-engine

I want to draw close to 300 small images on the canvas each frame. This takes a long time (40ms) which means frame rate drops below 30. The issue is drawBitmap performance.

1. I tried normal canvas
2. I tried surface view with a background thread.

none of the above give me a satisfactory frame rate.

What is the best way to do this? do I have to use drawing engines like unity3d?

Comment: Do they all actually move?  If not, you probably can get away with only drawing a subset.  But 300 is a lot.  Unity may be overreaction (or not, if you're making a game), but OpenGL is definitely something you can consider.

Comment: Yes they are moving, hence updated every frame.